# Identification info that my wireless card sends to the (wifi) network

Tags: wifi, wireless, mac-address

Are any other identification information that my wireless card sends to the Wi-Fi network apart from the MAC address ? If so are they changeable?

Let's say, for example, that I connect to a Wi-Fi network once and then I change my MAC address to reconnect: can anybody see that I am the same user ?

Answer (score 2):

The only identifying information that the *card* sends is the MAC address.

However, other parts of your system can send identifying information as well.  For example, the DHCP client may send your computer's name to the DHCP server; if you browse the web, you can be identified through browser fingerprinting.